# OSX Cocoa App: Which method for rescaling an image is best with respect to image quality?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Currently I am doing the following to rescale an image:

```
CGImageRef resizeCGImage(CGImageRef image, size_t new_width, size_t new_height)
{


CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image);
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, new_width,new_height,
                                             8,
                                             new_width*4,
                                             colorspace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

if (context != NULL)
{
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0 , 0, new_width, new_height), image);
    CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return imgRef;
}

return NULL;

}
```

When I rescale from 1920x1080 to 1280x720, the resulting image quality is too low. It is most noticeable around small text (which becomes hard to read).

Is there a better way (offered by the Cocoa APIs) to rescale an image ? By "better" I mean better image quality.

Answer (score 2):

Try Core Image with the CILanczosScaleTransform filter.